# How to make full USB format using terminal

Tags: command-line, format, delete

I want to know how to make a full format of a storage drive from the terminal, How to delete byte by byte from the storage drive (without using quick format as traditional methods). Is this even possible?

Hope you can help me thanks!

Comment: Wiping the existing data of a drive is different from creating a new file system. You can use dd to wipe a disk/partition/file, see https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_wipe_a_hard_drive_clean_in_Linux. Be extremely carefull if you want/need to venture into dd, though,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer*: you need to wipe the drive first, then reformat in order to reformat a drive, making sure none of the previously stored data survives.

You are doing a "full format" whenever you use the `mkfs -t vfat` or `mkfs.vfat` command. You cannot use formatting to wipe the existing binary data off a drive. After formatting, a new file system is in place. While the old data are not anymore accessible, they still exist on the drive and may be accessed using specialized tools such as data recovery software.

If your intention is to wipe these data, you need other tools. The tool `dd` can be used to overwrite an entire disk or partition or a file with zero data. For example, a command such as

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=1M
```

will overwrite all data on partition `/dev/sda2` with zeros. All of the partition data is wiped, so after this, a new file system needs to be created on the partition. Substituting `/dev/sda2` by `/dev/sda` will overwrite the entire drive, including the partition table. To wipe individual files, you are safer using the `shred` or `wipe` commands.

Warning: the `dd` command must be run as root. It writes at the low level and is extremely dangerous if you do not know exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for